# Finding Text In A Webpage

Tags: python, html

I am using this code to connect to supremenewyork and find out if an item is out of stock or in stock.
The search does not seem to be working

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/xqfitokcd/sqt46dyvb'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all("sold out")

print(text)
```

I have the html code that clearly shows the sold out text.

```
<b class="button sold-out">sold out</b>
```

Comment: you probably want `soup.findAll("b", {"class": "button sold-out"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag with its desired class like:

```
soup.findAll("b", {"class": "button sold-out"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to specify `text='sold out'`

```
text = soup.find_all(text='sold out')    
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the signature of our `find_all` function:

```
find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)
```

This function can be used in many different ways. The most popular one would be finding elements by their tag names. For that, you use the *name* and *attrs* arguments:

```
soup.find_all("b", {"class": "button sold-out"})
```

This command finds all the tags `<b class="button sold-out"></b>`.

If you however really want to search for a text and not for an HTML tag you can use the *string* argument:

```
import re
soup.find_all(string=re.compile"sold out")
```

Or if you want to find all tags that contain a certain string you can call:

```
soup.find_all("b", string=re.compile"sold out")
```